# Google Chrome keeps crashing for reasons unknown

Tags: google-chrome

So last night while I was working all of a sudden on Chrome something happened where my cursor got locked on the default.  Meaning when I hovered over a link it wouldn't change into the hand, when I hovered over text it wouldn't change into the bar, etc.  Kind of annoying I assumed something got locked somewhere and that closing and reopening Chrome would fix it.  It didn't, and neither did rebooting.  Kind of confused as to how this could happen I uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome.  Opened up google.com hovered over a link and voila back to normal.  Then I went to setup syncing again since I had just reinstalled and once the sync was complete I was back to the locked cursor.

Kind of a PITA since I'm a web developer and working on a project and like to see things as the client would, but alas I trucked on.  As I kept working Chrome continuously would crash every 10 minutes or so [Chrome had crashed on me maybe twice in the years I've been using it up until now.]  The crashes were sporatic and didn't seem to be attached to any single page as sometimes I would be working on a client site and it would crash and sometimes I'd be taking a break and just browsing Facebook.  Also just to note the crash closed all tabs not just one so it seems like something deeper than a single tab acting out.

Today I wake up and my cursor is back to acting normally [yippie!] but the crashing continues.  I thought maybe one of my extensions had updated in the background and was now going wild but after uninstalling all extensions [I only have a couple] the crashes continued.

I hate to ask this question because it seems like something I'd pull my hair out over if my mom asked me but:  why does Chrome keep crashing on me?  Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot further?

Here's a screenshot of the error message after Chrome crashes:

[image]

Comment: In some older versions sync was faulty, and you needed to turn it off. It should have been fixed by now.